# Ordering by multiple parameters in a custom WordPress query loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, infinite-scroll

I've implemented an infinite scroll and in search results upon ordering by price or any custom value it doesn't work.
Here inside my enqueued script:-

```
 isset($_GET['orderby'])?$ga_order_by = $_GET['orderby']: $ga_order_by = '';//grabbing the orderby value 



  if( gettype($result) == 'object') {
    $ga_wp_query = new \WP_Query([ 'post_type'=> ['product_variation', 'product'], 'post__in' => $includes, 'orderby' => ['post__in',$ga_order_by], 'order' => 'ASC' ]);//so i'm ordering by search results and dynamically grabbed value.
  } else {
    $ga_wp_query = new \WP_Query([ 'post_type'=> 'product', 'post__in' => $includes, 'orderby' => ['post__in',$ga_order_by], 'order' => 'ASC']);
  }

 $args['ga_search_posts'] = json_encode($ga_wp_query->query_vars);
```

Inside my ajax handling  function call  upon search:-

```
 $search_query = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['search_posts'] ), true );//this is the   $args['ga_search_posts'] i'm posting via my javascript

    $search_query['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $search_query['posts_per_page'] = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $search_query['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;

    wc_set_loop_prop( 'total', $_POST['search_count'] );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'labtag_show_price' );

    ob_start();

    query_posts( $search_query);


    if (  have_posts() ) {//product loop
      if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
               the_post();
              wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            }
          }
  } 
  $data = ob_get_clean();
  die($data); 
  exit;
```

This works except if I try to order by any parameter say price etc. Can't 'orderby' => ['post__in',$ga_order_by] declared like an array?If not should I be passing all my posts ids to the ajax handler iterate them and sort them (if this is the case, how to handle my custom order_by params)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

So, with WordPress' OrderBy, you have a couple of different options.

If you want both parameters to be sorted in the same direction of ASC or DESC, then the argument anticipates a single string, with the parameters separated by a space.

> **Multiple 'orderby' values**  Display pages ordered by 'title' and
>   'menu_order'. (title is dominant):
>
> ```
> $args = array(
>   'post_type' => 'page',
>   'orderby'   => 'title menu_order',
>   'order'     => 'ASC',
> );
> $query = new WP_Query( $args );
> ```

You use an array when you are sorting each parameter differently:

> **Multiple 'orderby' values using an array**
>
> ```
> > Display pages ordered by 'title' and 'menu_order' with different sort
> > orders (ASC/DESC) (available since Version 4.0):
> $args = array(
>   'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'DESC', 'menu_order' => 'ASC' )
> );
> $query = new WP_Query( $args );
> ```

In your case, since you are using a variable, consider building the string and then using this within your arguments array, i.e.:

```
//start with a space, then .= to concatenate the $_GET parameter with the space if it's set, or clear the string if it's not.
$ga_order_by = " ";   
isset($_GET['orderby'])?$ga_order_by .= $_GET['orderby']: $ga_order_by = '';
//grabbing the orderby value and building our complete string.
            $orderBy = 'post__in'.$ga_order_by;        
          if (gettype($result) == 'object') {
              $ga_wp_query = new \WP_Query([ 'post_type'=> ['product_variation', 'product'], 'post__in' => $includes, 'orderby' => $orderBy , 'order' => 'ASC' ]);//so i'm ordering by search results and dynamically grabbed value.
          } else {
              $ga_wp_query = new \WP_Query([ 'post_type'=> 'product', 'post__in' => $includes, 'orderby' => $orderBy, 'order' => 'ASC']);
          }
```

Comment: Thank you it is very helpful, trying it like a string as per your answer like this        $orderBy = 'post__in'.$ga_order_by;  and editing it as per my situation, did the job

Comment: Hi Caitlyn, I'm now stuck in improving the speed of the scroll... I added more code here to be specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583343/improving-the-speed-of-a-custom-infinite-scroll. Any insights on how to handle this situation?Thanks

Comment: Since it's lengthy to post everything in one post i divided it into two posts.Please look into this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282847/improving-the-performance-of-a-custom-developed-scroll. and let me know your opinion. Thanks